# python Gtk app failed with this error xcb xlib threads sequence lost failed

Tags: gtk3, pygtk, xlib, pygobject, xcb

I had a pyGObject app and I run that. all things work fine until on a button clicked signal I need to run a def. it has a long loop and I run that with the

```
def on_launch_btn_clicked(self,button): 
    _thread.start_new_thread(launch,["thread"])


def launch(thread):
    lines_list = open("../line.txt").split()
    for line in lines_list:
        select = machinestate.objects.get(id=1)
        if not select.pause:
            #my process
        else:
            def pause_lcd()
            return "pause" #it for come out of def and close thread but I don't know it close that or not
```

this loop is in another .py file

function it works like a charm, next I had a pause button it changes database pause field to True and my loop every iteration check database to saw what is changed. when it saw pause is True it run

```
def pause_lcd():
    app = app_list[0]
    app.pause_action()
```

I run Gtk app in this def

```
app_list = list()
def main(thread):
    app = GUI()
    app_list.append(app)
    Gdk.threads_init()
    Gtk.main()
```

in my GUI class I have pause_action method

```
def pause_action(self):
    self.pause_btn.set_sensitive(True)
    self.pause_btn.hide()
    self.resume_btn.show()
```

when I clicked on pause button some time I got this error

```
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queen
[xcb] Most likely this is a mulity-threaded client and XinitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that
pyhton: ../../src/xcb_io.c:263 poll_for_event: Assertion '!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost failed.
```

I had a bunch of thread side this threads like machine info, clock, machine temp and ...

what I do wrongs??

PS: this app run in a Django project and I use Django model in this it is an app of Django but it runs a Gtk app

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that something with the XCB or the X11 server is wrong (bug). I received the same error message from different applications on a specific X server (using X11 over ssh).

Error message with emacs:

```
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
emacs: xcb_io.c:263: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
```

Error message with eclipse:

```
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
java: xcb_io.c:263: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
```